# How to check OS variables and use them with same name as Python variable from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

hopefully i can explain right what i am trying to do. I want to check if variables giving from a list, exists in OS, if so, use the same OS variable name and value in python.

This is how am i doing it right now but i think it is a lot of code and if want more os variables i would be bigger. So what could be a good starting to do this smarter and more efficient?

OS (linux) variables

```sh
export WEB_URL="https://google.com"
export WEB_USERNAME="Foo"
export WEB_PASSWORD="Bar"
```

```py
# Check os env variables
if "WEB_URL" in os.environ:
    web_url = os.environ.get("WEB_URL")
else:
    logger.error("No URL os env find please check")

if "WEB_USERNAME" in os.environ:
    web_username = os.environ.get("WEB_USERNAME")
else:
    logger.error("No USERNAME os env find please check")

if "WEB_PASSWORD" in os.environ:
    web_password = os.environ.get("WEB_PASSWORD")
else:
    logger.error("No PASSWORD os env find please check")
```

must be somthing like this to start with?

```py
os_variables = ["WEB_URL", "WEB_USERNAME", "WEB_PASSWORD"]

for var in os_variables:
    if var in os.environ:
        print(var.lower(), "=", os.environ.get(f"{var}"))
```

result:

```
web_url = https://google.com
web_username = Foo
web_password = Bar
```

so what is printed here above should literally be the variable, just to show what i mean

Comment: What you are calling "OS variables" are more properly called "environment variables". The loop you show is a typical refactoring of this kind of repeated code.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use the same names? Otherwise, `os.environ` is already a dictionary that you're accessing, so other than checking for key existence, do you really need to assign the values any further? You could just as easily make a sub-dictionary with all the necessary key-values

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes i need the variables further in my python script, first i want to check if they are existing.

Comment: `os.environ.get()` will return `None`. You can also provide a default value to `.get()`. My point is that you could just pass around `os.environ` wherever you really need the variables, or you can build some config class wrapper around it that does the validation checking. Otherwise, using a list all-at-once is perfectly valid to what you're doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a compromise I finally came up with this as a solution

```py
env_variables = ('WEB_URL', 'WEB_USERNAME', 'WEB_PASSWORD')


def check_env(var):
    for var in env_variables:
        if var in os.environ:
            if os.environ[var] == "":
                logging.error(f'{var} is empty, please set a value')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            logging.error(
                f'{var} does not exist, please setup this env variable')
            sys.exit()


check_env(env_variables)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly you will need to make use of [eval()](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/) and [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Maybe something along those lines:

```
exec(str(eval(var.lower(), "=", "'", os.environ.get(f"{var}")"'")))
```

Evaluating first should give you something like `web_url = 'https://google.com'`. If this is turned into a string it can be executed, but be careful with global and local variables in this case.

Comment: Thanks, i will check that out. what would be the best option to check some specific env variables and use them in python after check if they exists?. Or should i ask what should you do to solve this? After some readings about eval and exec i prefer not to use them since the are risky and keep using my duplicated if else statement